# Formation of Hematite on Mars via Perchlorates as an Oxidizer

Tags: geology, geochemistry, mineralogy, mars, iron

[Hematite on Mars](https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/spotlight/hematite01.html) is generally thought to have formed either in pools of water or from volcanic activity.

A comment to the answer to the question: *[How do hematite and magnetite form?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/6910/how-do-hematite-and-magnetite-form)* states that sodium hypochlorite can act as an oxidizer to help form hematite.

I know hypochlorite is different from perchlorate, but [Mars contains so much perchlorate](https://www.nasa.gov/ames/ocs/workshops/pom) that its soils are considered to be toxic to life.

Could the perchlorates on Mars have been influential in the formation of hematite?

Comment: Perchlorate are strong oxidisers and can definitely lead to formation of hematite. Whether there was/is enough perchlorate on Mars to form most of the hematite there, good question.